# Vue JS Dynamicly change img

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to change the parameter in: src = "Krug", to something else, for example
By standard I have code. And I need to change it to 'krivkerekrest' on the click of one button or to the click of another button on 'maloeperekrest' and this should not be in any sequence. My backdrop: 6 pictures and by clicking on one of them, the picture on which I clicked opens at this place (I attached a photo for clarity)

````
        <div class="normperekrestie"><img 
        :src="normperekrestie" 
        style="cursor: pointer;"
        width="80" 
@click="make the same picture'"
        height="80" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="textcols-item3">
        <div class="rec"><img 
        :src="rec" 
        style="cursor: pointer;"
        width="80" 
@click="make the same picture'"
        height="80" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="textcols-item3">
        <div class="maloeperekrest"><img 
        :src="zakrashkrug" 
        style="cursor: pointer;"
        width="80" 
@click="make the same picture'"
        height="80" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ViewCross">
<img 
:src="Krug" //this parameter should change per click
width="200"
height="200" />
</div>```


export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return {
      Krug: require('/src/assets/svg/krug.svg'),
      krivkerekrest: require('/src/assets/svg/kriv-kerekrest.svg'),
      maloeperekrest: require('/src/assets/svg/maloe-perekrest.svg'),
      normperekrestie: require('/src/assets/svg/norm-perekrestie.svg'),
      rec: require('/src/assets/svg/rec.svg'),
      zakrashkrug: require('/src/assets/svg/zakrash-krug.svg'),
    }
  }

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zsal.png
````

Comment: Please format your code well.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, I suggest you read [List Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) and [Event Handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) in the documentation.

I haven't tested it but you could do something like the below, i.e. make an array that contains all your images, loop through them in the template and then when you click one of them, update a property that shows the clicked image.

```
<div>
    <div class="textcols-item3" v-for="imgSrc in imgSrcs">
        <img 
            :src="imgSrc" 
            style="cursor: pointer;"
            width="80" 
            @click="clickedImgSrc = imgSrc"
            height="80" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <img 
            :src="clickedImgSrc"
            width="200"
            height="200"
            v-if="clickedImgSrc && clickedImgSrc.length" />
    </div>
</div>

export default {
    name: 'App',
    data() {
        return {
            clickedImgSrc: null,
            imgSrcs: [
                require('/src/assets/svg/krug.svg'),
                require('/src/assets/svg/kriv-kerekrest.svg'),
                require('/src/assets/svg/maloe-perekrest.svg'),
                require('/src/assets/svg/norm-perekrestie.svg'),
                require('/src/assets/svg/rec.svg'),
                require('/src/assets/svg/zakrash-krug.svg')
            ]
        }
    }
}
```